# Eclipse shows an error but gcc compiles fine

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt

I have this MCVE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

auto wrapperMain( const std::vector<std::string> & commandLineArguments ) -> void
{
    printf( "argc=%d\n", commandLineArguments.size() );
}

int main( int argc, char * argv [] )
{
    wrapperMain( { argv, argv + argc } );
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <- Eclipse does not like this
}
```

It compiles fine with gcc 7.3 using the highest warning and pedantic options for C++17 [even it is not a C++17 feature].

Eclipse underlines `wrapperMain` and shows this error message:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void wrapperMain(const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string
   <char,std::char_traits<char>,
   std::allocator<char>>,std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string
   <char,std::char_traits<char>,
   std::allocator<char>>>> &)
'
```

I know I can disable this underlined error using the Eclipse `@suppress` directive:

`wrapperMain( { argv, argv + argc } ); // @suppress("Invalid arguments")`

but I would like to fix it in general.

**My question: Is it a Eclipse bug or is a setting missing?**

Comment: Off topic, but I suggest using C++ header files instead of C header files for C++ code.  `<cstdlib>` and `<cstdio>`.

Comment: Looks like an Eclipse bug to me.  May not be caught up on the latest C++ idioms.  If you change the wrapperMain signature to `void wrapperMain(CommandLineArgumens const&)` does Eclipse's C++ parser work then?  How about eliminating the using and put in the `std::vector<std::string> const&` as the parameter?

Comment: @Eljay Question updated. Nothing helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost certainly a bug in Eclipse CDT. I filed [bug 531322](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=531322) to track.

**UPDATE**: The bug has now been fixed.

Comment: May be a dup of 349849.

Comment: This works: `const CommandLineArguments & tmp = { argv, argv + argc }; wrapperMain( tmp);` so it seems Eclipse has a problem understanding `{ argv, argv + argc }` correctly.

Comment: @Eljay: It's not a dup of 349849. That bug report concerns an older variant of C++11 that GCC 4.4 supported, while this issue is with standard C++11.

Comment: @AlBundy: Note, the bug has now been fixed.

Comment: @AlBundy: I would suggest the [Eclipse bug tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT).

Comment: It seems to be fixed - but only particularly. I submitted a new [bug 532903](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=532903) which is quiet similar..